# Trying to save the file from amazon s3 on web server in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am trying to save the file from amazon s3 in laravel,but can not able to save it on the server.Please check and let me know is it correct ?

$fileUrl =  Input::get('actual_file_url') ;
        $fileNameWithExtension = substr($fileUrl, strrpos($fileUrl, '/') + 1);

```
    $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
    $file = $disk->get($fileNameWithExtension);
    Storage::disk('local')->put($fileNameWithExtension,$file);

    $storagePath  = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
```

Comment: you get any error?

Comment: Why would you want to store it on your web server when you have an s3 bucket?

Comment: i am totally blank about amazon s3..How it can implement on laravel 5.5 or above